# change the characters of xml in actionscript

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

Hi community I have the following problem,

given this xml

```
<test>
    <comp>
        <id>1</id>
        <content>bar</content>
    </comp>
    <comp>
        <id>2</id>
        <content>foo</content>
    </comp>
</test>
```

I want to change the value of the content of the comp element with id 2. Therefore I loop with a foreach loop

```
for each (var x : XML in testXML.children()) {
                    if (x.id == 2) {
                        for each (var element : XML in x.Children()) {
                            if (element.localName() == "content") {
                                element = "new content";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

now when reaching the point `element = "new content";` my programm tells me I cannot give element the value new content as this is a string and element is xml. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Sebastian

Comment: ok just found it out... I used element.* = "new content" now it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using E4X instead of loops.

To access the element use:

```
xml.comp.(id == 2).content
```

To modify it's contents, use

```
xml.comp.(id == 2).content.* = "new content";
```

Much shorter :)

Comment: Ah great thanks for that answer, I like E4X but did not know the conditions. This is great.